# Mockito: set value to spy object but get null

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I have a test case where I want to see if a property is set correctly during the execution:

```
ContainerRequestContext requestContext = spy(ContainerRequestContext.class);
someMethodThatSetsTheSecurityContext(requestContext);

verify(requestContext).setSecurityContext(argument.capture());
assertEquals("myUserName", argument.getValue().getUserPrincipal().getName());
assertNotNull(requestContext.getSecurityContext());
```

Now if I run this, the verify() and assertEquals() methods return true, but for some reason the requestContext.getSecurityContext() is null.
I understand that for mocked object there is no real implementation behind, but I thought the spied object should work in this case.

Comment: Why do you need to spy? Couldn't you simply assert that `requestContext.getSecurityContext().getUserPrincipal().getName()` is equal to "myUserName"? Why jump through hoops via spys?

Comment: I also need to stub some methods of the ContainerRequestContext, that is why I am using a spy object.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Mockito.argThat instead and see if it changes it:

```
verify(requestContext).setSecurityContext(Mockito.argThat(x -> x.getValue().getUserPrincipal().getName().equals("myUserName")));
```